# Creating a custom round button in android

Tags: android, button

Can anyone help me out here. I am trying to create a small round button that would represent a lottery ball using a very simple self created XML class round_button.xml. However I keep getting the error over and over even when Ive put the code through a w3schools validator that " Error parsing XML: junk after document element." I cannot see what the issue is here and maybe I am missing something very clear, I dont know. Could anyone please help me out. Here is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" />
    <solid
        android:color="#FF0000" 
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are just missing a bit of concept of closing the tags. You have extra `/` over `android:shape="oval" />`. You are already closing the tag at the end with `</shape>` so no need to use `/>`.

Secondly you haven't ended `<solid` tag with `/>`. So try something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <solid
        android:color="#FF0000" />
</shape>
```

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" /> 
    <solid
     android:color="#FF0000" />          .......should this not fix it?

Comment: No. Then your `solid` tag is completely outside the `shape` tag. `solid` is a property of your `shape`. So its shud be defined before closing the `<shape>` tag and after opening the `<shape>`. Its not independent of it. Hope its a bit clear now.

Comment: thanks @Shobhit and that has done the job!! as you can tell I am still new to android but am enjoying the learning experience! thanks again

Comment: Hope you got the concept of the shape and its properties. Also the reason why we have used the `solid` tag inside the shape. Glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You messed up tags. You have closed shape before end and not closed solid tag.
Try this one.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" 
>
    <solid android:color="#FF0000" />
</shape>
```